# Navigation doesn't render when wp is hosted

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I have created a theme on my local host and it works fine. I am using the walker function in order to get the bootstrap navigation. However when I upload the site on godaddy the navigation doesn't render.

If I try to create a new menu from the wp-admin panel at godaddy I do not get the the names of the pages that I have created for the walker function to render.

If you need any info I can support with code samples. Maybe the question is too brought and I cannot decide what code am I supposed to post in order to help.

Any idea how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I got it. I had to create the pages first and then add them to the menu at the hosted wordpress.